# Use restfb to retrieve likes of current user

Tags: facebook-graph-api, restfb

I am using restfb library to retrieve user information. How can i retrieve which movies, music, books he has liked?

FB Graph API says that we can use following to retrieve such information

```
Movies: https://graph.facebook.com/me/movies?access_token=...
Music: https://graph.facebook.com/me/music?access_token=...
Books: https://graph.facebook.com/me/books?access_token=...
```

However, if I use the following in my code,

```
facebookClient.fetchConnectionPage("me/movies", ...);
```

I get errors.

What needs to be done?

Thanks
Ajay

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter in this function is the full URL, for example, "https://graph.facebook.com/me/movies".

Answer (score 0):

that could help you:

```
    Connection<Page> fetchConnection = facebookClient.fetchConnection( "me/movies", Page.class );

    for ( Page page : fetchConnection.getData() )
    {
        System.out.println( page.getName() );
    }
```